# How to customize collection element in symfony2 forms

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I have a simple form related to a user in which i'm adding a collection of phone numbers (another form).

I can get it working with javascript but i want to customize the rendering of each phone input.

The same thing is working with a simple field by doing this :

```
{% block _elementId_widget %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="btnInvertNames" value="{{ "form.invertNames"|trans }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

To add a button after the widget, but not working with collections..

Answer (score 0):

A solution i found is to write a new "Form Type" and to customize its template :

Look here for [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)